# Восстановление m файла

Tags: файлы, matlab

Нечаянно сохранила новый m- файл под тем же именем, что и старый. Есть ли возможность восстановить старый файл.

Comment: @coder675, это утверждение конкретно про матлаб или в принципе?

Comment: Есть специальные программы которые ищут файлы на всем жестком диске. Которые при перезаписи не записались поверх. Если матлаб поверх не записал его, то можно найти. Вам найдет кучу файлов и придется его искать. https://ru.wikihow.com/%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D1%8B

Answer (score 1):

Теоретически есть возможность искать удалённые файлы на диске, но неизвестно, удаляется ли файл, или же просто открывается на запись и записывается поверх. Во втором случае ничего восстановить не удастся.

Если программа, в которой выполнялось редактирование, ещё открыта, можно попытаться нажимать в ней <kbd>отмена</kbd> до тех пор, пока не вернёшься к оригинальному состоянию файла. После этого сохранить файл и начать нажимать <kbd>повторить</kbd>, чтобы вернуться к актуальному состоянию. Ну и вместо второй части можно просто предварительно сделать копию текущего файла.

Думаю, матлаб достаточно адекватная программа, чтобы не ограничивать историю изменений и можно было откатиться к исходному файлу.